# MYSQL: SELECT * FROM table WHERE created_time < NOW() or NOW().replace(second=0)?

Tags: mysql, django

In details, I am using Django model.

1) `MyModel.objects.filter(created_time__lte=timezone.now())`

VS

2) `MyModel.objects.filter(created_time__lte=timezone.now().replace(second=0))`

Whether 2) is better than 1), without considering the accuracy, for it seems that 2) will hit the cache of mysql?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the queries will be executed in less than 1 minute, the second one will be more efficient.

Regardless, you would need a LOT of traffic to actually gain something by doing this

"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"